# Cómo dividir un archivo .txt con Java en varios archivos como líneas tenga el archivo?

Tags: java, txt

soy nuevo en esto de Java y quizá se me ocurrió algo que necesito.

Tengo un archivo .txt con varias líneas de información, entre las cuales sólo un pequeño texto varía. Será posible leer ese archivo en Java, y crear un archivo .txt por cada línea que tenga el archivo original, con el contenido de cada línea?

Para ser más gráficos:

Mi archivo tiene información dispuesta así:

*Mon Mar 01 04:00:01 UTC 2021 ,soporte@linktic.com,BackupStartJob,On-premise,AWS-FCP-SERVIDORADICIONAL*

*Tue Mar 02 04:00:01 UTC 2021 ,soporte@linktic.com,BackupStartJob,On-premise,AWS-FCP-SERVIDORADICIONAL*

*Wed Mar 03 04:00:01 UTC 2021 ,soporte@linktic.com,BackupStartJob,On-premise,AWS-FCP-SERVIDORADICIONAL*

Lo que quisiera es recorrer ese archivo, y con cada línea crear un archivo nuevo (nombrado puede ser con un número consecutivo). Es posible?

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo hasta el momento? De ser así te invito a compartir un [mre] y enfocar tu pregunta a dudas que tengas con respecto al código. Adicionalmente te invito a realizar el [tour] y ganar tu primera medalla.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En algún momento llegué a hacer algo similar, te comparto el código.

```
public class ExtractorMain {
    private static final int LIMIT = 2;  //Este lo vas cambiando de acuerdo a tu necesidad, es decir, es el numéro de líneas por archivo
    public static void main(String args[]) {
            Scanner sc=  new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Ingresa la ruta de tu archivo txt y despues presiona enter.");
            System.out.println("Ejemplo: C:\\Users\\Omar\\Downloads\\Doc\\archivo.txt");
            String fileName = sc.nextLine();  
            
            System.out.println("Ingresa la ruta en donde se crearan los archivos txt y despues presiona enter.");
        

System.out.println("Ejemplo: C:\\Users\\Omar\\Downloads\\Doc");
        String url = sc.nextLine();  

        String sheetName="";
        int counter = 1;
        int counterBook = 1;        
        FileReader fis = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter bw=null;
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            if(!file.exists()) {
                System.out.println("El archivo no existe.");
                throw new RuntimeException("No existe el archivo.");
            }else {
                System.out.println("Leyendo archivo...");
            }
            fis = new FileReader(file);
            br = new BufferedReader(fis);
            String line;
            String nameFile = "";
            
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Linea "+counter+ " ["+line+"]");
                if(line.equals("")) {
                    continue;
                }
                String[] columns = line.split("\\|"); //En tu caso revisa como quedaría, aquí lo maneje por |
                sheetName = columns[0];             
                
                if(counter==1) {
                    nameFile= getFileName(counterBook,url);
                    try {
                        if(bw!=null)
                            bw.close(); // Cerramos el buffer
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Error al cerrar archivo: "+nameFile+"--->" +e);
                    }
                    
                    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(nameFile));
                    counterBook++;
                }
                
                bw.write(line);

                if(counter==LIMIT) {
                    counter=1;
                }else {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            
            System.out.println("Gracias por la espera.....:)");

            try {
                if(bw!=null)
                    bw.close(); // Cerramos el buffer
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error in finally");
            }

            
        }
    

private static String getFileName(int counterBook,String url) {
    String name = url+"\\archivoGenerado" + counterBook + ".txt";
    return name;
}
```

}

Comment: Gracias. Mencionar que, para el funcionamiento de este código, la ruta del archivo y la carpeta de destino deben estar cerradas antes de iniciar la ejecución.